# Safari on iOS unable to show a normal CSS font as bold

Tags: android, css, ios, fonts

I am using the "Kaushan Script" font on a web page, and it is only defined for normal font weight. But I use it for bold text, which is normally no problem because the most browsers can emulate a bold font.

It works fine on every browser on PC and Android, but not for Safari on iOS, it still shows as normal font weight. Is this a general problem for Safari, or is it just for this specific font?

I could include a bold font file to solve the problem. Do you know of any font conversion tool that can take a woff2 file and make the font more bold?

Comment: This is not a problem for iOS Mobile Safari, it's the font problem. If the font does not have a bold variant, a browser should NOT display a bold font. You should consider using a **web font** with the font variants you need instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari won't display a font out of its available font-weights.

So if that font doesn't have bold type then it won't be bold in safari.